# How to protect concurrent write of same number in Django Tastypie

Tags: django, concurrency, locking, tastypie

A REST API implemented with Tastypie, which is to write a number into a table. To prevent 2 users to write same number into the table, and  `is_valid()` is implemented in `HelloValidation`. `transaction.atomic()` is used to prevent concurrent write.

```
    Models.py

    class HelloModel
       ...


    RestApi.py

    from django.db import transaction
    from tastypie import resources 
    from tastypie import validation 

    class HelloValidation(Validation):

      def is_valid(self, bundle, request=None):
        """Length validation."""    
        return status


    class HelloResource(ModelResource):

      class Meta(object):

        queryset = models.HelloModel.objects.all()

        validation = HelloValidation()


      def dispatch(self, request_type, request, **kwargs):
        with transaction.atomic():
          response = super(HelloResource, self).dispatch(request_type,
                                                     request,
                                                     **kwargs)
        return response
```

This is my understanding:

1. Without `transaction.atomic()`. If 2 user write same number at same time, `is_valid()` will be True. For example, table has 1 row with number 10, 2 users write same number 20. Each 'thread' read table with 10, and 20 is valid, as it is not same number as 10. There is no protection of writing same number. Is that correct?
2. I added `transaction.atomic()`, but I am not sure what it does in this case, because `is_valid` = True. Does `transaction.atomic()` lock the table? If it locks the table, `is_valid()` can't be performed currently for 2 users, then, I know following code work. But, I am not sure if `transaction.atomic()` locks the table.

Comment: Checkout `select_for_update` [1] to see if that gets you what you need. I'm not familiar with TastyPie but I would look for a way to override a method (`get_object_list`?) [2] on the view that allows your to return a queryset with `select_for_update` applied.  [1] https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.select_for_update [2] https://django-tastypie.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resources.html#id8

Comment: get_object_list() is to access custom model. In my case, I don't use custom model. So, I am not sure what to overwrite in Tastypie to use select_for_update()